# Obtaining orthogonal left and right eigenvectors at similar computational speed in R/Python?

Tags: python, r, wolfram-mathematica, scientific-computing, eigenvector

My goal is to find right and left eigenvectors of a diagonalizable, non-symmetric matrix `m` without inversion but so that they are still orthogonal to each other/ From `?eigen` I would like to find the V^(-1) in V Lmbd V^(-1) without having to use `solve` but so that they still have the property `V^(-1) V = Identity`.

In R, `eigen(m)$vectors` provides right eigenvectors by default. An often proposed solution is to find left ones by running `eigen(t(m))$vectors`. However, these are not by default such that `t(eigen(t(m))$vectors) %*% eigen(m)$vectors` evaluates to the identity.

How can I implement this in R (or Python)? I have seen this example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36889/best-way-to-compute-row-eigenvectors), which emphasises computing left and right eigenvectors with the same efficiency but is written in Mathematica. How can I translate this example?

The overall goal is to find eigenprojections made up of outer products of left and right eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the fact that for a matrix of right eigenvectors $R$ and left eigenvectors $L$, we have the following relation:

$ R R^{\prime}L = R$ which can be solved efficiently using `qr.solve(e$vectors%*%t(e$vectors),e$vectors)` for `e <- eigen(m)` for some matrix `m`.